# How to use Google web oauth2 in backend service in Spring Java

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, google-api

I have a login page that allows to log in into spring application using Google Account. This is all user need to do. The rest are some calculations inside application and the results should be put to google sheet.

Login part:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable().antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login.html").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login().permitAll()
                .and().
                logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/");
        
    }
}
```

Now I need to use Google Api to access user google sheets, but as back-end. There is no more interaction in UI (web).

In service I can access oauth2 authentication like this:

```java
            SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
            Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();
```

but I don't know how to use this token in google-api like communication with google sheets. Probably I need to have special getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT) function.

```java
Sheets service = new Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
```

Small example would be nice. I'm digging internet as crazy and I can't find a way to do this. I guess it'll be something easy.

Comment: Have you tried this tutorial to implement this: https://www.baeldung.com/google-sheets-java-client ?

Comment: it uses "OAuth 2.0 Credentials" so it is example for windows or cmd line applications. I tried if it works and yes I can compile and build such a simple app. The problem is that there's no example how to use web authorization in google api authorization.